# setCenter doesn't seem to accept any objects i feed into it

Tags: javascript

I have been working on this for hours, but I can't seem to find the correct object feed into setCenter for this particular scenario:

```
    var map,
        currentPositionMarker,
        mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(14.668626, 121.24295)

    function initializeMap(){
        map = new google.maps.Map(_('map'), {
           zoom: 18,
           center: mapCenter,
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
            mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}
         });
    }

    function locError(error) { alert("current position not be found");}

    function setCurrentPosition(pos) {

        currentPositionMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(
                pos.coords.latitude,
                pos.coords.longitude
            ),
            title: "Current Position"
        });
        map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(
                pos.coords.latitude,
                pos.coords.longitude
            ));

    }

    function displayAndWatch(position) {

        setCurrentPosition(position);
        watchCurrentPosition(position);
    }

    function watchCurrentPosition(pos) {

        var positionTimer = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
            function (position) {
                setMarkerPosition(
                    currentPositionMarker,
                    position
                );
                **map.setCenter(google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude,pos.coords.latitude));**
            });
    }

    function setMarkerPosition(marker, position) {
        marker.setPosition(
            new google.maps.LatLng(
                position.coords.latitude,
                position.coords.longitude)
        );
    }

    function initLocationProcedure() {
        initializeMap();
         infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({  maxWidth: 400 });
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayAndWatch, locError);
        } else { alert("Geolocation API not supported");  }
    }
```

(it's especially frustrating as I have to drive around the block to verify if each change works!).
Anyone know what I am doing wrong in the map.setCenter line above?

Comment: You don't have `new` in front of the `google.maps.LatLng` when you are doing the `setCenter` call, so you aren't getting a LatLng object, you are getting `undefined` since a non-constructor call to LatLng does not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set it like this:

```
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
```

Comment: the updated code now centers initially on the correct location, but doesn't track my location.  It stays centered on the original place, and I drive off the screen, and back onto it later.